# Shell script to switch between MRI and jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

Working on a project which uses jRuby, but locally when I work I often use MRI because it's faster.

Now switching between to is a major annoyance, this is how I switch from jruby to MRI:

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.5
sed -i.bak 3s/.*/ruby" '2.1.5'"/ Gemfile
```

Which replaces my Gemfile and specifies the right version of ruby. Now I wanted to create two executables from `bin/` folder of my rails project, one called `mri` and another one `jruby` so I could switch back and forth between the two using a single command, and so that everyone who work in a team can use the same.

Problem with this is that, when the shell executes, the RVM doesn't change the ruby version in my current session. So naturally I get this message :

**Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5**

1. Is this a good approach to what I'm trying to do? 
   pretty sure I'm not the first person trying this
2. Do you already have something that works for you?

Comment: You need to `source` the RVM scripts again.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt what do you mean? I should `source bin/mri` ?

Comment: You need to re-source some of the files located under `~/.rvm/scripts` after changing your Gemfile. Maybe you try changing the Ruby version in the Gemfile _first_, and then running the `rvm use` command.

Comment: I'd suggest against using a different ruby interpreter in dev and production. I'd actually suggest against using a different version, let alone a different interpreting language. Although the bootup time is considerably longer for jruby, it could save headaches later by using it locally.

Comment: I'm with @joonty here. Use the same version of the same interpreter for dev and production. If you're using a different one then having a Continuous Integration server with a production version is a must.

Comment: @joonty and tadman I understand that, and it's the case with me 90 % of the time, but sometimes there are tests that take forever and it's faster to execute them with MRI, and plus I can use spring gem. So this is not all the time for me, most of the time I use jruby like production does.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt which files under `~/.rvm/scripts` should I re-source.

Comment: You don't need to include ruby version in the Gemfile at all, just take it out. But you may need to re `bundle install` when you switch interpreters, as the concrete gems meeting the specs in your Gemfile may change based on platform. But `bundle install` often runs transparently when needed, so you might not notice. Things might work how you want if you simply remove ruby version from the gemfile. I think Spring is going to end up a nightmare though. Personally I prefer chruby to rvm, it doesn't give me any trouble in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out, you need to re-source the rvm scripts.
You probably could just source `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_rc` again, as they should be sourced there.

That being said, I haven't had this problem with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), but I only swap between MRI versions.
There is also a spec for a `.ruby-version` file [see here](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/1912050) that both RVM and rbenv honor.

For bundling bin stubs you can [specify a bin path](http://bundler.io/v1.10/bundle_binstubs.html) with `bundle binstubs --path mri-bin`.